# PHP PDO Failure to open stream

Tags: php, pdo, yii

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm overlooking, but it's driving me a bit crazy.  I'm on a Ubuntu machine running LAMP.  I have several sites running on this machine using Php / MySql without a hassle.  I've recently begun a site using the Yii framework, but I don't think that this is a Yii quesiton.  Maybe it is.  Anyway...

My other sites used mysqli so Yii's PDO requirement is new to me.  I did a quick -i|grep on the PDO and it came back as installed / enabled so no worries.  I installed the framework, created a quick test site and database.  However, when I try to connect to the database via the site I get an error telling me that the PDO failed.  Specifically, a failure to open the stream.  So it's not finding the PDO even though the PDO is installed.  The Yii site is in the same web folder as the other sites, so there can't be a path issue.

From a Yii standpoint, if that is where the problem lies...  I was able to create controllers for the various database tables in Gii, but pulled the same unable to open stream error when I tried to generate CRUD for those tables.

For the record, yes, the MySql is enabled in the Yii main.php file.  Yes, the connection string is correct.  I'm a bit at a loss as to why the PDO would fail to open if it lists as enabled.

Comment: What is your code for opening the connection? (Obviously obfuscate sensitive info)

Comment: have you checked using phpInfo to make sure the server is actually using PDO? specifically the mysql version?

Comment: Valid question.  As it turns out I have no idea.  It's a bit confusing at this point.  PDO shows as enabled in the CLI, which is why it shows as enabled when I do php -i|grep PDO.  However, it does not show up on php(info).  Of course, the CLI and the web server are running to different .ini files.  HOWEVER... when I compare the two .ini files they are exactly the same, character for character where PDO is concerned.  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: There is a small app included with the framework that checks to make sure all the requirements are met (I think it's called requirements). What does that show?

Comment: http://localhost/yii/requirements/ PDO MySQL extension  Passed?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this just for the search engines.  I still have no idea exactly what the problem might have been.  As I mentioned, PDO was showing enabled from the CLI, but not from phpinfo.  This is possible because the CLI uses a different php.ini than does apache2.  However, after a complete re-install of php I was still running into the same problem.  I again opened both .ini files in gedit and went line by line with them using a non-case sensitive find on "pdo".  They were absolutely, completely identical.  Finally, I gave up trying to understand the problem and just went for the easy fix. I removed the .ini from Apache2 and replaced it with the one from cli, and voila! I have PDO enabled in Apache2.  I still have absolutely no idea what the problem was, but at least it's solved.